# Magic link flow with WSO2 identity server

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-api-manager, deep-linking, wso2-identity-server

I have a requirement to generate deep links/magic links for end users. The users will receive the link via email and on click of it requires to be auto logged in (passwordless login).

The identity server that is being used is WSO2 identity server. I also have WSO2 API manager.

Can you please suggest the mechanism via which WSO2 identity server would enable the view of the link/page without requiring the user to explicitly login.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supported out-of-the-box. But you can try to write a custom authenticator.

See this [doc](https://wso2docs.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/IS520/pages/47022621/Writing+a+Custom+Federated+Authenticator) and [article](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/10/15/custom-authenticator-for-wso2-identity-server-wso2is-sso-login/).

Answer (score 0):

Magic Link Authentication is now supported OOTB in WSO2 Identity Server.

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/passwordless/magic-link/