# WSO2 Authorisation_code grant redirecting to authenticationendpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

When I am trying to use the Authorisation_code, it is always redirecting to authenticationendpoint, like below:

[image]

This is not aligned with what I see here https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Generating+Access+Tokens+with+Authorization+Code+-+Authorization+Code+Grant+Type

I am expecting something like below:

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location:
https://client.example.com/cb?code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA

Answer (score 0):

You need to login first before it gives you an authorization code. Quoting from the same doc.

> The client initiates the flow by directing the resource owner's
>   user-agent to the authorization endpoint (you can use the /authorize
>   endpoint for the authorization code grant type of OAuth 2.0). It
>   includes the client identifier, response_type, requested scope, and a
>   redirection URI to which the authorization server sends the user-agent
>   back after granting access. The authorization server authenticates the
>   resource owner (via the user-agent) and establishes whether the
>   resource owner granted or denied the client's access request. Assuming
>   the resource owner grants access, the authorization server then
>   redirects the user-agent back to the client using the redirection URI
>   provided earlier. The redirection URI includes an authorization code.

To understand by an example, please have a look at [this article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/securing-your-web-service-with-oauth2-using-wso2-identity-server-1/). Please note this is an old article. So configurations might be different, but you can refer the example.

Comment: I don't want the user to login. I want the flow to be auto login. This is in relation to deeplinks which are generated and sent via emails. When a user clicks on the deep link the user is never prompted for credentials but are auto logged in and are taken directly to the page. I had a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166449/magic-link-flow-with-wso2-identity-server

Comment: I don't think that is supported out of the box. You may have a look at custom authenticators. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Writing+a+Custom+Federated+Authenticator